# Finding a positive real $\beta$ such that $\beta < \alpha$ and ${\beta}^2 > 3$?

Tags: real-analysis

Given $ \alpha > 0 $ and $ {\alpha}^2 > 3$.

How can I find a $\beta$ in terms of $ \alpha $ such that $0 < \beta < \alpha$ and ${\beta}^2 > 3$?

I would be very thankful if you also give the "mathematical thinking" explicitly that goes into constructing $\beta$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can proceed like this: set $\beta=\alpha-t$, with $0<t<\alpha$. Then the inequality you want to satisfy becomes
$$
(\alpha-t)^2>3
$$
The inequality is satisfied for
$$
t<\alpha-\sqrt{3}
\qquad\text{or}\qquad
t>\alpha+\sqrt{3}
$$
so you can take
$$
t=\frac{\alpha-\sqrt{3}}{2}
$$

If you have $\alpha$ rational and want to find $\beta$ also rational, observe that
$$
t^2-2\alpha t+\alpha^2-3>0
$$
is certainly satisfied if $-2\alpha t+\alpha^2-3>0$, so we can choose
$$
0<t<\frac{\alpha^2-3}{2\alpha}
$$
Note that
$$
0<\frac{\alpha^2-3}{4\alpha}<\alpha
$$
and you're done.

Comment: Can I find $\beta$ in terms of $\alpha$ without assuming the existence of $\sqrt{3}$ i.e. if i am not allowed to use irrational numbers?

Comment: @vivekkumar In the case $\alpha$ is rational, yes; if it is irrational, not really.

Answer (score 2):

You could take $\beta = \frac{\alpha + \sqrt{3}}{2}$ so that $\sqrt{3} < \beta < \alpha $. Alternatively, take $\beta^2 = \frac{\alpha^2+3}{2}$ so that $3 < \beta^2 < \alpha$.